# Python filter not working with pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

If you create a `filter(fn, list)`, if the "fn" returns a `tensor([True])` for a given element, why does the element of the list incorrectly get excluded?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is because tensor([True]) does not immediately evaluate to True for some reason. You need to wrap a bool(...) around tensor([True]) and it will work.